# Using slim-lang template engine to stream XML outside Rails request cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, template-engine, slim-lang

I am looking for options to generate XML in Ruby using a template engine that supports streaming, so I can generate huge XML files to disk without worrying much about memory.

I found [Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim), and it seems that it is able to generate [XML](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/slim-template/FptWFYRXpCs/discussion). It has a *streaming* option that works inside Rails, but I am not sure how to use it outside the Rails requests cycle, as I am interested in using it to generate XML files to disk in a background task (in a Rails webapp anyway, if this context helps).

Any pointers to code would be much appreciated (looking at the github repo and the test suite wasn't very informative: it seemed to me all streaming tests are inside the Rails request cycle.)

Comment: include *slim* gem, then register the slim renderer, and you then are able to manually render the templates. Like this: `Slim::Template.new('template.slim').render(scope)`

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in data **streaming** through Slim, to a **file**. How does that address this? Sorry, not clear to me :(

Comment: what do you mean streaming, to send the result to `IO`, to `File`, what exactly?

Comment: _streaming_ means that the template engine does not generate the whole result (text or XML elements) in memory and then dumps it into a file; quite the opposite, it is able to send content progressively until all is generated. The HAML template engine does not support streaming (all output is generated in memory before being serialised to IO); this is why Slim captured my attention. So, when you call `render` in Slim, is it possible to pass an IO object to serialise data on it as the template gets processed?

Comment: do you wish using the streaming inside the rails or outside?

Comment: Outside Rails; inside Rails request cycle is explained in the documentation afaik. Tnx!

Comment: Well, which framework will you use? if is noone, you shell not need the streaming.

Comment: This will run as a background task in TorqueBox, i.e. JRuby. We will have Rails objects and classes, I bet, but it is outside the http request cycle. I wish it were that simple :-|

Comment: strangely, i believe it depends on how have you use the rails infrastructore. if you have use the rails `#render` method, I believe you can enable the streaming, but if not...